# If $f$ has an unbound derivative - is $f$ necessarily non-Lipshitz?

Tags: calculus, lipschitz-functions

So we assume that $f$ is differentiable on some closed interval $[a,b]$ and has a derivative $f'$ which is not bounded.
Is there a way to show that $f$ is non-Lipshitz?

If not, is there some intuitive counter example (like of the form $x^p\sin{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)})$?

Comment: Try it the other way around: If $f$ is Lipschitz continuous (and differentiable) then the derivative is bounded.

Comment: This is immediate from the definition of $f'$. Hint: If $\lim_{h\to0}\phi(h)>M$ then there exists $h\ne0$ such that $\phi(h)>M$...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that conclusion holds. A proof by contraposition would be to show that (for a differentiable function $f$ on $[a, b]$)

$$
 \text{$f$ is Lipschitz} \implies \text{$f'$ is bounded.} 
$$

So assume that
$f$ is Lipschitz continuous with some Lipschitz constant $L$. Then
$$
 \left\vert \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} \right \vert \le L
$$
for all $x, x_0 \in [a, b]$ with $x \ne x_0$. Taking the limit $x \to x_0$ it follows that
$$
 |f'(x_0)| \le L
$$
for all $x_0 \in [a, b]$, i.e. $f'$ is bounded.